# How can an Int32 structure include an "int" field in mscorlib?

Tags: .net, struct, integer, internals

I decided to study the source code of mscorlib and opened the file responsible for the implementation of the int32 type (https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/int32.cs). It contains the declaration of the Int32 structure (which is literally the "int" data type), but in the same structure there is a field with the "int" data type, which in theory should cause an error.

```
    public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
        , IComparable<Int32>, IEquatable<Int32>
///     , IArithmetic<Int32>
#else
    public struct Int32 : IComparable, IFormattable, IConvertible
#endif
    {
        internal int m_value;
```

I really wonder how it works and what I missed, I will be grateful for help.